# ¿Cómo borrar en modo seguro sin clave primaria en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 2 tablas: **USERS (usuarios)** y **FRIENDSHIPS (amistades)**.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USERS; 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS (
    id  INTEGER UNSIGNED    PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nick    VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FRIENDSHIPS; 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FRIENDSHIPS (
    id  INTEGER UNSIGNED    PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_user INTEGER UNSIGNED    NOT NULL REFERENCES USERS (id),
    id_friend   INTEGER UNSIGNED    NOT NULL REFERENCES USERS (id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Datos para pruebas

```
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (10, 'user1');
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (20, 'user2');

INSERT INTO FRIENDSHIPS VALUES (100, 10, 20); # user1 - user2
INSERT INTO FRIENDSHIPS VALUES (200, 20, 10); # user2 - user1
```

Quiero eliminar 2 registros de la tabla **FRIENDSHIPS** que están relacionados uno con el otro por la id de la tabla **USERS**, pero me lanza el **error 1093** que me aconseja activar el *safe mode (modo seguro)* y yo no sé si es del todo seguro desactivar (valga la redundancia) el modo seguro o no para realizar lo que intento.

### Consulta que lanza el error 1093

```
DELETE FROM FRIENDSHIPS WHERE id = (SELECT fr.id as _id from FRIENDSHIPS fr WHERE fr.id_user = 1 AND fr.id_friend = 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente no he mirado cual es el error 1093, pero no entiendo muy bien la query. ¿Por qué haces una subconsulta sobre la misma tabla de la que quieres borrar los registros?
¿Por qué no haces directamente esto?:

```
DELETE FROM FRIENDSHIPS WHERE id_user = 1 AND id_friend = 3;
```

Por otro lado, deduzco que en la tabla FRIENDSHIPS quizá tendrás "la inversa", es decir, id_friend = 1 e id_user = 3. Si los quieres incluir, debes haces un `or` con esta última condición. Es decir:

```
DELETE FROM FRIENDSHIPS WHERE (id_user = 1 AND id_friend = 3) OR (id_user = 3 AND id_friend = 1);
```

Y por último, si te sigue dando error y pidiéndote que desactives el modo seguro, siempre te lo puedes "saltar" añadiendo una condición extra como por ejemplo `AND id > 0`

---

Update: Añado mi último comentario a la respuesta, puesto que creo que también es relevante y soluciona el problema:

*Igualmente, no creo que te tengas que preocupar por no usar el modo seguro. Añade esta línea `SET SLQ_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` antes de la query y el SET a 1 después. Eso seguro que funciona.*

Comment: Hola Roger, estoy en las mismas, en este caso error 1175, que desactive también el modo seguro.

Comment: ¿Probaste lo último que te dije? Añadir la condición `id > 0` en el `WHERE` de la query: `DELETE FROM FRIENDSHIPS WHERE ((id_user = 1 AND id_friend = 3) OR (id_user = 3 AND id_friend = 1)) AND id > 0;`

Comment: Sí, y lo mismo ocurre.

Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: Pues que raro, acostumbro a saltarme ese error utilizando ese truquillo. Igualmente, no creo que te tengas que preocupar por no usar el modo seguro. Añade esta línea `SET SLQ_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` antes de la query y el SET a 1 después. Eso seguro que funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Trabajar sin el modo seguro no es muy recomendable, la respuesta anterior debería haber resuelto tu problema, por lo que si ese error persiste es porque debes tener registros con esos campos repetidos y estarías borrando mas de uno al mismo tiempo con esa consulta. Es decir:

id | id_user | id_friend |

---

1  |    4    |     3     |

---

2  |    4    |     3     |

Si quieres que sean registros únicos, coloca los tres campos como claves primarias y así no se repetiran. De esta manera podrás borrar usando ese criterio y evitando quitar el modo seguro.